# PHP routing: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have an HTML form defined as follows:

```html
<form action="{{route('save.checkout')}}" method="POST">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="{{session()->get('cart')->totalprice}}">
  <div class="cart_navigation">
    <a class="continue-btn" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"> </i>&nbsp; خرید را ادامه دهید
    </a> 
    <a class="checkout-btn" href="{{route('save.checkout')}}">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i> ادامه به  پرداخت
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

The following error is being thrown when submitting the form:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

my route is:

```
route::post('/savecheckout','BasketController@checkout')->name('save.checkout');
```

and the checkout function:

```php
public function checkout(Request $request){
  $user = auth()->user()->id;
  $order = new order();
  $order->user_id = $user;
  $order->amount = $request->input('amount');
  $order->status = 0;
  $order->save();
  $order = order::where('status' ,0)->where('user_id', $user)->first();
  return view('checkout.index', compact('order'));
}
```

Comment: You are currently using the server with `php artisan server`, or with Nginx or other type

Comment: I have rephrased the question for clarity. It is very helpful to add correct formatting which helps read the question. I've reformatted ther HTML and PHP part for readability.

Comment: Do you have any other get route that has the same endpoints? Or can you show your routes for better understanding ?

Comment: @MrLizzard yeah i use php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem . it was a silly mistake i changed my button type to submit

Answer (score 0):

if you are beginning with Laravel so i would like to contribute something to make your programming better & safer for future projects.

- always validate your input
- use of try & catch blocks
- show appropriate error message to your users so that you can also
  debug it in future.

so the modified code will be look like:

```
public function checkout(Request $request){
    // use Validator; (add this after namespace to import validator)
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'user_id' => 'required|integer|max:11',
        'amount' => 'required|numeric',
        'status' => 'sometimes|integer|max:1',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator);
    }
    try {
        $user = auth()->user()->id;
        $order = new order();
        $order->user_id = $user;
        $order->amount = $request->input('amount');
        $order->status = 0;
        $order->save();
        $request->session()->flash('message', 'Order Successfully Created');
        $order = order::where('status' ,0)->where('user_id', $user)->first();
        return view('checkout.index', compact('order'));
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        dd($e->getMessage()); // it will show the error message with, you can replace this block with redirect code or anything else..
    }
}
```

for showing error & success message in front-end use below code in your checkout > index.blade.php template (just a sample code, you can make it more better by using your own CSS & styles)

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="note note-error">
        <h4>Error..!!</h4>
        <p>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <div class="alert alert-danger fade in m-b-15">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                {{ $error }}
                <span class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</span></div>
            @endforeach
        </p>
    </div>
@endif
```